# Automatically map an instance to one of its properties based on the inferred type in Swift

Tags: swift

I find the compositional syntax of SwiftUI very intuitive and would like to use a similar approach for composing/modifying URLs. Here's what I have in mind:

```
struct URLTemplate {
    let url: String
}
```

A template `url` might look something like this:

```bash
https://myserver.com/resource.jpg?width={width}
```

Now I might want to modify this URL as follows:

```
urlTemplate
  .width(400)        // replace the stencil → https://myserver.com/resource.jpg?width=400
  .format(.portrait) // append a parameter: &format=portrait
  .withWatermark()   // append a parameter: &watermark=true
```

To accomplish this, I would add extension functions on `URLTemplate` as follows:

```
extensions URLTemplate {
    func width(_ width: Int) -> URLTemplate { ... }
    func format(_ format: Format) -> URLTemplate { ... }
    func withWatermark() -> URLTemplate { ... }
}
```

Each of these functions would modify the `url` and wrap it in a new `URLTemplate` instance. Works.

The problem is on the caller side:

In the end, I want to have a URL, not a `URLTemplate`, because that's what I use to make requests. Then why not just use a `URL` instance in the first place instead of this custom type? Well, because I need some other information for making these URL modifications that each modifier needs to know.

I could of course just extract the modified URL in the end like this:

```
urlTemplate
  .width(400)
  .format(.portrait)
  .withWatermark()
  .url                         // ← here
```

but this is super annoying as it leads to redundant boilerplate code as I would need to do this *every* time I want to use a URL to make some request.

So what I would wish for is some kind of automagic type inference whenever a URL is expected. When the compiler cannot infer a concrete type, the following expression would return a `URLTemplate`:

```
let urlTemplate = urlTemplate
  .width(400)
  .format(.portrait)
  .withWatermark()             // → returns self (type: URLTemplate)
```

However, when the compiler infers a `URL` type from the context, it should automatically understand that a URL is expected and implicitly return the `url` instead:

```
let url: URL = urlTemplate     // notice the explicit type annotation
  .width(400)
  .format(.portrait)
  .withWatermark()             // → implicitly returns self.url (type: URL)
```

Is there a feature like this in Swift and if not, can I somehow build this kind of behavior on my own using existing Swift language features?

*Note:* It should be obvious that I want to be able to use an arbitrary number of modifiers, for example, just omit the `withWatermark()` modifier above. So in this case, `urlTemplate.width(400).format(.portrait)` should also be interpreted as a `URL` when a `URL` type is inferred.

Comment: My initial thought is that this is doable when you want to return something that conforms to a protocol (you could make `URLTemplate` conform to `URLProtocol`), but I think you may be out of luck if you need to have it end up as a concrete class

Comment: I have something similar but what I do is that I send my URLTemplate to my network class and it internally converts it to an URL (actually an URLRequest), this way I only need to do it in one place in my code. This could be an alternative to what you are looking for since I feel the usage is simple and clean and the actual conversion is hidden.

Comment: @jnpdx: Yup, that's the problem. As @JoakimDanielson points out, one solution would be to just have another layer in between that knows how to interpret a `URLTemplate`, but I'm actually writing some kind of a framework and as such, I do not control the "down stream" i.e. how the constructed instance is used.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to do what you want to do and modify the return type when you are chaining function calls.

My suggestion is instead to add the functions as extensions to `URLComponents` to get something that is close to what you want but also makes use of the functionality provided by this type.

Here is an examples of two modifiers and a utility method

```
extension URLComponents {
    func width(_ width: Int) -> Self {
        append(queryItem: URLQueryItem(name: "width", value: "\(width)"))
    }

    func orientation(_ orientation: SomeEnum) -> Self {
        append(queryItem: URLQueryItem(name: "orientation", value: orientation.rawValue))
    }

    private func append(queryItem: URLQueryItem) -> Self {
        var temp = self
        var queryItems = self.queryItems ?? []
        queryItems.append(queryItem)
        temp.queryItems = queryItems
        return temp
    }
    // or change its signature as below and create the URLQueryItem inside it 
    // private func append(name: String, value: String?) -> Self
}
```

Use case:

```
let components = URLComponents(string: "https://myserver.com/resource.jpg")!
    .width(400)
    .orientation(.portrait)

print(components.url!)

let url = URLComponents(string: "https://myserver.com/resource.jpg")!
    .orientation(.portrait)
    .width(300)
    .url

print(url!.absoluteString)
```

> https://myserver.com/resource.jpg?width=400&orientation=portrait
> https://myserver.com/resource.jpg?orientation=portrait&width=300

Comment: I agree that this is probably the closest we can get with Swift. Unfortunately, it doesn't meet the two requirements mentioned in my question that I was hoping to somehow include in a solution: 1) to avoid having to append `.url` on the caller side every time and 2) to be able to use custom information stored in the "root" type (to which those modifiers are applied) which doesn't work with native types like `URLComponents` as I do not own these types and extensions cannot have stored properties. It's still a great answer and I think many devs will benefit from it! Thanks!

Comment: I didn’t know about any custom information from the question but to solve that you could use your own URLTemplate but use the URLComponents as the internal type instead of String, it would still leave you with 1) but I think you must have that.

Comment: I apologize, I probably didn't succeed in formulating that clear enough. It's what I wrote as an answer to the question "Then why not just use a URL instance in the first place instead of this custom type?". Well, that's probably the best way to go, using URLComponents wrapped in a custom type.